# Error with mysql

Tags: database, hibernate, metadata

I am trying to install ejbca to use mysql but there is a problem. I am not so sure of what are the errors or how to fix them. The errors are:

```
2011-11-03 14:16:15,191 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (main) could not get database metadata
2011-11-03 14:16:15,353 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (main) could not complete schema update
2011-11-03 14:16:31,656 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (main) Unable to get managed connection for MySQLDB; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for MySQLDB)
2011-11-03 14:16:31,731 ERROR [org.ejbca.ui.web.admin.configuration.StartServicesServlet] (main) Error creating CAAdminSession: 
2011-11-03 14:16:32,577 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (main) Unable to get managed connection for MySQLDB; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for MySQLDB)
2011-11-03 14:16:32,774 ERROR [org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl] (main) Unable to mark for rollback on PersistenceException: 
2011-11-03 14:16:32,945 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/ejbca/adminweb]] (main) StandardWrapper.Throwable
2011-11-03 14:16:33,256 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/ejbca/adminweb]] (main) Servlet /ejbca/adminweb threw load() exception
2011-11-03 14:16:34,250 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (main) Unable to get managed connection for MySQLDB; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for MySQLDB)
2011-11-03 14:16:34,250 ERROR [org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl] (main) Unable to mark for rollback on PersistenceException: 
2011-11-03 14:16:34,277 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/ejbca/publicweb/status]] (main) StandardWrapper.Throwable
2011-11-03 14:16:34,454 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/ejbca/publicweb/status]] (main) Servlet /ejbca/publicweb/status threw load() exception
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had used grep to get those errors out if the log file. I have however solved the problem. The problem was just the location of the mysql connector. I had unzipped the whole zip file into the jboss/server/default/lib. This created an additional folder so the connector was in ~/lib/mysqlconnector/mysqlconnector.jar
I moved the .jar file up one level and the errors were solved.:)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the complete error trace? I suspect that you're missing the MySQL driver in whatever AS you're using (I'm presuming JBoss).

If that's the case, check out the documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/getting_started/v4/html/db.html).